# How can i use display information in a label acording to min and max values i put in a textbox c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display this information in a label. 
If i put a number in the textbox between 50 and 60, I want the label to show "Good". 
I hope someone can help me with this thanks.

Comment: @michu **Close-voting**: *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.*

Comment: @HighCore i don't know where to start man

Comment: @michu [WPFTutorial.net](http://wpftutorial.net/Home.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first add one button to your form. Then write below code in click event of your button:

```
int text = int.Parse(TextBoxName.text);
if(text>50 && text<60)
{
  LableName.text="Good";
}
```